# How to perform bulk delete operation in wp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have written as below code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'submitted_form'; 
$randomFact = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM " .$table);
$NumRows = count((array) $randomFact);
?>
<form name="delform" method="post" action="">
 <table>
 <?php for($i=0; $i<=$NumRows-1; $i++){ ?>
 <tr>
 <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php print          $randomFact[$i]->id; ?>"> </td>
<td><?php print $randomFact[$i]->name; ?></td>
<td><?php print $randomFact[$i]->address; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
 <tr>
<td><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
 <?php if($delete): ?>
  <?php for($i=0; $i<=$NumRows-1; $i++){ ?>
  <?php $id = $checkbox[$i]; ?>
   <?php $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_submitted_form WHERE id =".$id); ?>
    <?php } ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   </table>
  </form>
```

The deletion operation doesn't work... Please help me

Comment: Where `$delete` is defined? I think you should use `$_POST['delete']`.

Comment: I have tried by using $_POST['delete'], it still doesnot work..

Comment: Actually I am using the tutorial http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/8.html

Comment: In this tutorial $delete is not defined properly

Comment: Okay, I think tha same should be done with `$checkbox` - replace to `$_POST['checkbox']`. Also try to echo (`echo, print, var_dump)` your variables to see their values.

Comment: It's not working after using $_POST['checkbox']

Comment: What values do you get before `if($delete):`. Are there any errors?

Comment: Dump variables, check their values, maybe `$delete` is `false` and the deletion doesn't work.

Comment: It does not return any value, it is empty

Comment: And if dump `$_POST`?

Comment: then it returns 'Delete'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34744/discussion-between-u-mulder-and-nida)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here changes what you need to do:
Variables `$delete` and `$checkbox` are not defined. You can define them or use $_POST vars instead.

```
// test what we have here:
//echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST),'</pre>';
if (isset($_POST['delete'])):
    // i dont think that you should use $NumRows here, cause user 
    // can check 1 or 2 checkboxes, not all of them
    $size = count($_POST['checkbox']);
    for ($i=0; $i<=$size-1; $i++) {
        $id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_submitted_form WHERE id =".$id);
    }
endif;
```

Also you don't have to substract `1` in a loop. You can use:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++)
```

And dont' forget to check if `$_POST['checkbox'][$i]` is really integer to avoid mysql-injections.